# Can be used ExportToStream with using?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

In our web we have some Crytal Report. The code to send the reports to the user is exporting as Stream :

```
MyReport report = new MyReport();
report.SetDataSource(myData);

Stream reportStream = report.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, localFilename);

SendReportToUser(reportStream)            

reportStream.Close();
reportStream.Dispose();

report.Close();
report.Dispose();
```

My question is Can I substitute this code for the next ? With a `using` and avoid to call Stream `Close()` and `Dispose()` methods?

```
using (var report = new MyReport();)
{
     report.SetDataSource(myData);

     using (var reportStream = report.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, localFilename)
     {
          SendReportToUser(reportStream)            
     }
}
```

I know that CrystalReport implements it's own version of Stream FileStreamDeleteOnClose and I have been looking through in internet and It seems that everybody avoid use `using` and instead of it call `Close()` and `Dispose()` for the resulting Stream.

What is the reason? Has Crystal Report some memory leaks and I must always invoke `Close()` and `Dipose()` method of the resulting Stream as I'm doing?

Thanks

Comment: the fact that you can even compile when using `using` says that they implemented the interface. do you have any reason to believe that their implementation does not work? maybe you've just been looking at old examples (that predate the `using` statement)?

Comment: The only reason is that all the example codes I've search call to Dispose and Close instead of using.

Comment: Well `using` statements are only syntactic sugar really, the compiler translates it to a call to dispose when all is said and done, so if there is a problem with their implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose()` you won't get around it by calling it manually instead.

Comment: This is my suspicion, that may be there is some issue with their Implementation FileStreamDeleteOnClose, because everybody calls `Dispose` and `Close`

Answer (score 0):

A using statement is simply a way of avoiding the boilerplate code for a `try { ... } finally { disposable.Dispose(); } block.

In your example the two code snippets are not equivalent - the using statement versions foregoes the call to Close the streams (although the difference between `Close` and `Dispose` should be nill in this example). And in the event of an exception in your first example, you will not close or dispose the report and / or the stream. I'd recommend the second version (that utilises using statements) - they make it easier to dispose of things correctly and at the appropriate time.

It's most likely that the example writers were not as familiar with the features of C# as they might be and omitted the using statement to keep the examples as similar across all languages as possible.